# pygame error - the code is not working

Tags: python, macos, pygame

This code is not working for me:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
red = (255,0,0)
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    gamedisplay.fill(red)
    pygame.display.update

pygame.quit()
quit
```

It doesn't give me a red background.

Comment: Did you mean `pygame.display.update()` (see also `quit()`)?

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the screen. Fix this line:

```
pygame.display.update
```

to

```
pygame.display.update()
```